# copy rows to a new worksheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a script which copies a row from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2, 
if the value for  the first column of Sheet 1 is greater or equal to 10.

```
Sub Macro1()

Cells(1, 1).Select
For i = 1 To ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

    Cells(i, 1).Select

    If ActiveCell.Value >= 10 Then
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select

        Rows(i & ":").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

     End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to the first answer, but a few differences. Here's some notes:

- Use a for-each loop to go through a range (it's not as fast as using a variant array, but keeps things simple and offers better speed than a for loop.
- You may want add a "If IsNumeric(cell)" check before the value check.
- Don't use select - you don't need to and it wastes resources.
- Better to use the last cell used in A then the used range.

Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyRows()

Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 1

For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    If cell.Value >= 10 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: It would be the fastest because it does not depend on selection, but on direct manipulation of data through VBA

```
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim r_src As Range, r_dst As Range

    ' Pick 1st row and column of table
    Set r_src = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")
    Set r_dst = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4")

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim N_rows As Integer, N_cols As Integer

    'Find the size of the data
    N_rows = CountRows(r_src)
    N_cols = CountColumns(r_src)

    'Resize source range to entire table
    Set r_src = r_src.Resize(N_rows, N_cols)

    Dim src_vals() As Variant, dst_vals() As Variant
    'Get all the values from source
    src_vals = r_src.Value2

    ReDim dst_vals(1 To N_rows, 1 To N_cols)
    Dim k As Integer
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To N_rows
        ' Check first column
        If Val(src_vals(i, 1)) >= 10 Then
            ' Increment count
            k = k + 1
            ' Copy row values
            For j = 1 To N_cols
                dst_vals(k, j) = src_vals(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    ' Bring rows back into destination range
    If k > 0 Then
        r_dst.Resize(k, N_cols).Value2 = dst_vals
    End If
End Sub

Public Function CountRows(ByRef r As Range) As Integer
    CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End Function
Public Function CountColumns(ByRef r As Range) As Integer
    CountColumns = r.Worksheet.Range(r.End(xlToRight), r).Columns.Count
End Function
```

Here is a test case I run:

**Before**

[image: Sheet1]

**After**

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: I would argue that the method is too complex for the task on hand and any speed benefits would be outweighed by it. There are cleaner ways of using variant arrays as well.

Comment: I don't think this is grounds for a downvote. It is a working solution, it is robust, and instantaneous. The complexity is in the eye of the beholder here. And please elaborate more on a "cleaner" way to use `Variant` arrays.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll add an answer based on variant arrays later and more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set wsI = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = Sheets("Sheet2")

    LastRow = wsI.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    j = 1

    With wsI
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Val(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) >= 10 Then
                wsI.Rows(i).Copy wsO.Rows(j)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```